# Leostick Receiving message from Uno using USB jumpers cables

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I have a Arduino Uno which is looping over Serial.println("$testmessage"). Connected to this is a USB cable that i have cut and soldered male jumper leads to . I need to receive this message ("$testmessage") from the Uno using this USB cable without using the leosticks usb connector. After receiving the correct messgae from the Uno i plan to use Serial to send data from the leostick to my pc.

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to receive this message from the Uno.

Currently the the USB 5v and ground is connected to the leosticks 5V, GND pins. The Uno powers on and the the tx led is flashing every 100 milliseconds.

Can i just plug the green and white wires from the USB cable into D0&D1 and except it to work?

(Uno plugs into usb cable in the image)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0kbb.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While USB *is* a serial protocol, it's a completely different serial protocol than the RS-232-style logic-level serial protocol that the Serial library supports.  So the approach mentioned in the question has no logical chance of working.

Also, the USB electrical signal is differential (double-ended, or line-to-line, rather than single-ended, or line-to-ground).  So the mentioned approach has no electrical chance of working.

What may work is to wire from Tx on the Uno to Rxd1 on the Leostick, and from Rx to Txd1, unless that conflicts with the Leostick's USB-Serial link.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has any chance of working. You can't use USB to interface between the two devices, as the Leostick can't work as USB host. Your best bet is to use (software) serial.